# How to change the global value of a parameter when using a function in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, global-variables

This is what I want to achieve

```
Variable=0
Some_function(Variable)
print (Variable)
```

I want the output to be 1 (or anything else but 0)

I tried using global by defining `some_function` like this, but it gave me an error **"name 'Variable' is parameter and global"**

```
def Some_function(Variable):
    x=Variable+1
    global Variable
    Variable=x
```

Comment: If you know you are working with a global variable, you don't want or need a parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Variable** as your global variable and as function parameter.

Try:

```
def Some_function(Var):
    x=Var+1
    global Variable
    Variable=x

Variable=0
Some_function(Variable)
print (Variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same name for parameter and the globale variable

Answer (score 1):

The error message seem clear enough. Also, you wouldn't need to pass `Variable` as a parameter if you are using a global.

If you define

```py
def f():
    global x
    x += 1
```

Then the following script should not output an error :

```py
x = 1 # global
f(x)
print(x) # outputs 2
```

Another possibility :

```py
def f(y):
    return y+1
```

Which you can use like this :

```py
x = 1
x = f(x)
print(x) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify global variable, you should not use that name as function parameter.

```py
var = 0

def some_func():
    global var
    var += 1

some_func()
print(var)
```

Just use `global` keyword and modify variable you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
Variable = 0
def some_function(Variable):
    global x
    x = Variable + 1

some_function(Variable)
Variable = x
print(Variable)
```

Comment: Please don't just post the code, you should also include explanation why provided solution works.